# How to create nested json from an array with PHP

Tags: php, json

```
$my_array = array(
    "room" => array(
        array("id" =>"1", "message" => "This is a message") 
    )
);

echo json_encode($my_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

This is the output I got:

```
{"room":[{"id":"1","message":"This is a message"}]}
```

This is the output I want to get

```
{"room": { "id": 1, "message": "This is a message"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an array within in array:

```
"room" => array(
    array("id" => "1", "message" => "This is a message") 
)
```

The inner array has named keys, which get translated to JSON as an object.  But the outer array is just a standard array.

If you don't want the object wrapped in an array, don't wrap it in an array:

```
"room" => array("id" => "1", "message" => "This is a message")
```

**Edit:** I just noticed that you want `"1"` to be `1` as well.  Which you can achieve by replacing `"1"` with `1`:

```
"room" => array("id" => 1, "message" => "This is a message")
```